# Repartition failing with method not existing error in spark2.4.3

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I currently have spark version 2.4.3 and tried to use the repartition function on a textfile from hadoop. I get the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o110.coalesce. Trace:
      py4j.Py4JException: Method coalesce([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: can you post an example of the code, or a dummy code that is somewhat close to the real code?

Comment: it looks something like this: "testRDD = sc.textFile(temp.txt).zipwithIndex(); testRDD = testRDD.repartition(10)"

Comment: I have run the same code in a test and it runs fine spark.sparkContext.textFile(filePath).zipWithIndex().repartition(10).take(10), I ran it in spark 2.3 but these are really vanila use cases so should not be much different in 2.4

Comment: When I run the example from the pyspark docs in the interactive pyspark shell, it seems to work fine. It must be something with hadoop then.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing a list rather than an RDD into the function, which was causing the issue. Thanks for the help